# Add weighted average line to flot point chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I have a scatter (point) chart in jQuery's Flot.

I'd like to add a weighted average line to the point chart, as you can do in Excel charts. (Or a logarithmic or similar "line of best fit" would be acceptable, actually.)

Is this possible in Flot?

I can't see anything about it in [the docs](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/), but perhaps someone here knows how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this isn't something Flot does itself.

You can work out your own line of best fit by doing some [simple calculations](http://easycalculation.com/statistics/learn-regression.php) on your data. You can then plot the result using Flot. The link contains a worked example but is not Flot specific.